# Java/Android: adding/removing values to/from array by clicking a button?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to Java and Android. I have a seat reservation system. Each seat is represent using a button.

What I want to do is when user presses the button button should change it's color (blue->yellow) and the name of the button should be passed on to a array. If user presses that button again color of the button should go back to previous state and the value should be removed from the array.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code I hope it will work fr you:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.seat_1:
        {
            if (doesExist("1")){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                seats.add("1");
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.seat_2: {
            if (doesExist("2")){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                seats.add("2");
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.seat_3: {
            if (doesExist("3")){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                seats.add("3");
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

And also put this method somewhere in your Class:

```
public boolean doesExist(String buttonValue) {
    for (int a = 0 ; a < seats.size() ; a++){
        if (buttonValue.equalsIgnoreCase(seats.get(a))){
            seats.remove(seats.get(a));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I get an error. can't resolve method 'equalsIgnoreCase'

Comment: Just make sure your "seats" arralist datatype is String, because I have designed this code assuming your "seats" arraylist datatype is String.

Answer (score 1):

this is one solution you can use:

you need and array like below:

```
Boolean[] array = new Boolean[size];
Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.FALSE);
```

and later in `onClick` of each button(each seat) make it's position true/false ,like this:

```
seat3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           array[3] = !array[3];  
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

```
seat0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           array[0] = !array[0];  
           if(array[3]){
             seat0.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//selected seat
           }else{
             seat0.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//unselected seat
           }
        }
    });
seat1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           array[1] = !array[1];  
           if(array[1]){
             seat1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//selected seat
           }else{
             seat1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//unselected seat
           }
        }
    });
seat2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           array[2] = !array[2];
           if(array[2]){
             seat2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//selected seat
           }else{
             seat2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//unselected seat
           }  
        }
    });
```

add `onClick` for each seat like above.

and later compute array cells base on your need.

Comment: Arrays.fill() gives me an error. 'cannot resolve symbol 'fill'. why is that?

Comment: Yes. It used  java.util.Arrays;

Comment: ok, it should work but anyway you can use this either : for(int i = 0; i<size;i++) array[i] = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can write an onClick() for each button using switch statement

```
`public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.seat_1: {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            seats.add("1");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.seat_2: {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            seats.add("2");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.seat_3: {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            seats.add("3");
            break;
        }
  }`
```

Comment: how can i change the color again and remove it from array?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps (not tested, but should work).

```
  SparseBooleanArray mSeatsArray = new SparseBooleanArray();


    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.seat_1: {
                toggleReservation(view, 1);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.seat_2: {
                toggleReservation(view, 2);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.seat_3: {
                toggleReservation(view, 3);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    private void toggleReservation(View view, int i) {
        boolean isReserved = mSeatsArray.get(i, false);
        if (!isReserved) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mSeatsArray.put(i, true);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            mSeatsArray.put(i, false);
        }
    }


    private void getReservedNumbers() {  
        for (int i = 0; i < mSeatsArray.size(); i++) { 
            boolean isReserved = mSeatsArray.valueAt(i);
            if (isReserved) {
                int seatNumber = mSeatsArray.keyAt(i);   // do smth with reserved seats ()
                Log.e("MainActivity", "getReservedIndexes: " + seatNumber);
            }
        }
```